# Como obter colunas dos arquivos XLS no R

Tags: r, xls

Usando a ferramenta R, eu consegui abrir um arquivo XLS da seguinte forma:

```
require(xlsx)
coln = function(x) { 
  y = rbind(seq(1, ncol(x)))
  colnames(y) = colnames(x)
  rownames(y) = "col.number"
  return(y)
}
data = read.xlsx2(path, 1)  
coln(data)
x = 3 
data = read.xlsx2(path, 1, colClasses = c(rep("character", x), rep("numeric", ncol(data)-x+1)))
```

Eu consigo visualizar tudo que tem na minha planilha. Mas, gostaria de obter apenas os dados da coluna A e só depois usar os dados da coluna B para cálculo de uma função.

Como posso obter essas informações separadas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `read.xlsx2` tem um parâmetro chamado `colIndex` em que você pode especificar quais colunas (pela posição) você quer extrair.

Assim, no código abaixo, por exemplo, colocando `colIndex = c(1,3,4)` você extrairia as colunas 1, 3 e 4.

```
data = read.xlsx2(path, 1, 
                  colClasses = c(rep("character", x), 
                                 rep("numeric", ncol(data)-x+1)), 
                  colIndex = c(1,3,4))
```